# WordPress Multilingual Support for Multisite

Tags: wordpress, multilingual, multisite, wpml

I have one multisite with one custom post-type and multiple taxonomies and posts are generated using a third-party application.

Now I want to create a German addition site where content from the third-party application will be German and I want to show post listing with German translated strings, taxonomies, etc.

Any suggestion on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, I recommend using this plugin.
It works by automatically translating anything.
There are also various other options that can help you.

Link: https://pl.wordpress.org/plugins/google-language-translator/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I tried this plugin but it is failing in multisite.